# Looking for a free bootloader

Tags: operating-systems, bootloader

I've heard recommendations from other people before that simply having a bootloader can make it so much easier to add and remove operating systems from my system. What is the best (preferably free) one to have?

Comment: Why not just use GRUB?

Answer (score 12):

[GNU GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/). It's open source as well!

Although after installing a secondary OS such as Linux, it will automatically install GRUB for you and detect your other operating systems. Their is no need to install it standalone.

Comment: Grub tends to be the most recommended.  It's very flexible, and very extensible.  One guy even got 110 OS's installed and bootable via GRUB: http://www.justlinux.com/forum/showthread.php?t=143973

Comment: That's incredible I am speechless haha

Comment: So let's say then that I installed a Linux distro with GRUB and then decided to install Windows 7. Does GRUB make this any easier or prevent the Windows bootloader from clobbering GRUB?

Comment: I would usually install Windows first, I've never had a problem that way. You can then use a little program called mbrfix to remove GRUB if needed.

Comment: I'm thinking of the case where I need to reinstall Windows after the fact and it plows right over GRUB. I've also been burned before by GRUB, although I can't remember the exact details offhand.

Comment: You can't keep Windows from killing GRUB, but it's pretty trivial to slap GRUB right back up and get things running again. You can do it with an Ubuntu boot disk and one of the dozens of easily locatable online howtos.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) on my Intel Mac before, and it was pretty good. Probably depends on the system you use, I'm not sure how that works exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Does [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) take care of the bootloader part or just arrange the settings of whatever bootloader you have?